# Reading key-value json data into google sheet cells

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to bring in the "bid" values from each "ticker" from this API call https://api.etherdelta.com/returnTicker into Google Sheet cells.

An example cell value will have something like: `=crypt("PPT)`.

Here is the code I have so far, but I am having a hard time figuring out how I can get the data for each ticker (I know I haven't declared "ticker" anywhere in the code).

```
function crypt(ticker) {

  var url = "https://api.etherdelta.com/returnTicker";

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var text = response.getContentText();

  var json = JSON.parse(text);
  var price = json[bid];

  return parseFloat(bid);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the following modifications?

#### Modification points :

- Each ticker name has a header of `ETH_`.
- `ETH_` + ticker is a key of the object.

  - When `=crypt("PPT")` is used, the key is `ETH_PPT` and "bid" you want is in the value of `ETH_PPT`.

The modified script which was reflected above is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function crypt(ticker) {

  var url = "https://api.etherdelta.com/returnTicker";

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var text = response.getContentText();

  var json = JSON.parse(text);
  var price = json["ETH_" + ticker].bid; // Modified

  return parseFloat(price); // Modified

}
```

This modified script retrieves the value of `bid` for each ticker by putting `=crypt("PPT")` to a cell in the spreadsheet.

#### Note :

- It seems that an error response is sometimes returned from the URL.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!